# IBM Websphere Portal Menu Component Query String Parameter

Tags: menu, components, websphere-portal, wcm

When choosing the search criteria for a menu component in IBM Websphere Portal, I can also expand the "further option" box to include the ability to pass query string when calling the menu component, either directly through the URL or through the WCM API RenderingContext. However, the menu component then requires that I pass a value for that parameter, otherwise it will not return any result whatsoever. Is it possible to make the menu component search for content without passing values for the parameters that it is expecting? I am usinng WebSphere Portal 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly make a jsp component that checks the query params and if none are presents injects some defaults and then calls the menu component to render